# Changing HTML in .NET

Tags: .net, html-agility-pack

I have a few HTML files in which I need to change certain values.

So there can be a tag like so:

```
<div class="store">@Html.Action("Go","Now",new{Id=12,Type="Small"})</div>
```

in which the Id value has to be changed.

I tried doing this using HTML Agility Pack like so:

```
            var foos = from foo in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='Id']") select foo.InnerText.Replace("Id=50864","Id=55555");
```

Calling Save after this doesn't save the file as foos is a copy of the selection.

How do I save this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you miss typed  `"//div[@class='id']"`. It should be `"//div[@class='store']"`.
And change your code to this:

```
var nodes = page.SelectNodes("//div[@class='store']");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    node.InnerHtml = node.InnerHtml.Replace("Id=50864","Id=55555");                            
}
document.Save("NewFilePath");
```